# How can I truncate the tax class tables and not break my install?

Tags: database, tax-class

I'm having trouble editing and adding the Tax Classes in our current installation.

When I looked the classes up in the database I saw that a new entry gets a primary key of '0' and this is causing issues. I'm not sure what the issue is aside from not updating with the correct values after an edit or displaying '*An error occurred while saving this tax class.*' when trying to add a new Tax Class as the logs aren't showing anything. But from previous experience I'm almost certain its because of an Integrity constraint violation.

Previously when migrating our database I fixed the Integrity constraint violation issue for other tables by truncating them but I know that these tax tables have foreign key relations with some of the product tables so I want to proceed carefully.

How can I safely truncate these tables? I am working on a development environment so I have room to experiment. Also all the current products only use 1 tax class so I can re-add it later.

Answer (score 0):

You need to truncate `tax_calculation_rate` this table  and try again hope it will work. Before doing any truncate please keep backup of your db.